# Putting a comma after 'taking everything into account'

Tags: commas, writing

Is a comma after 'Taking everything into account' required when introducing the conclusion of an essay?

For instance:

> Taking everything into account(,) one should choose one's job paying attention to the fact that it should be pleasant.

Comment: It might depend on what follows. How would you complete the sentence? For example, compare: **Taking everything into account in this case, I think we should proceed** and **Taking everything into account, in this case I think we should proceed.**

Comment: @Ronald Sole I'm curious what kind of examples you could come up with. If the next thing is the subject of the sentence, I would always use a comma.

Comment: @RossMurray Now we're agreed!

Comment: Don't you think that 'in this case' is a bit redundant after 'taking everything into account'? :-)

Comment: @Aer On a different point, it's better to stick to **one's**, as in: **...one should choose one's job....* rather than **their job**, even though in practice ithe rule is seldom observed.

Comment: @RonaldSole of course it is, I haven't checked the devised context and hence missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @RossMurray It's a quick-fire example to illustrate the difference that the placing of a comma might make. I don't doubt that there are better examples if need be!

Comment: @RonaldSole Did you miss the smiley after my comment? We are allowed to have a bit of fun here by teasing each other, aren't we?

Comment: @RossMurray Mea culpa. Mea maxima culpa!

Answer (score 1):

A general principle is that if a phrase can be deleted from a sentence without changing the meaning of what remains, then that phrase should be enclosed in two commas, or one comma and the start/end of the sentence at the other end.

If I wrote 'Taking everything into account' as the opening words of any sentence, I would always then use a comma.

Note that I'm stating a general principle. In almost all cases after someone opened a sentence with that, they would then have the subject of the main sentence. If a subject is next, then a comma becomes mandatory.